# Trying to capture a form submit event, then not capture it again

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, calculator

Edit: @mhodges answered the question. Jsfiddle is updated. Thank you!

I have a little calculator/donation form that I am setting up. The form is simple: one input for a number, then the submit button performs a calculation and gains a new value, at which point I want it to link to a donation page. Here's some sample code:

```
<form id = "donation" action = "donation/page">
  <input id = "firstNumber" placeholder = "400.00">
  <input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Calculate Number">
</form>
```

And here's the jquery I have running it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#donation:not(.ready)").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    var amount = $("#firstNumber").val() / 5;
    $("#firstNumber").val(amount);
    $("#submit").val("Donate Now!");
    $("#donation").addClass("ready");
  });
});
```

Edit: Spelling and a link to a JS fiddle:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/oxpw5g0s/1/)

So the calculator works great and the new value shows up great in the input. My problem is that the value for the submit button isn't changing and the submit button continues to perform the calculation even after getting the .ready class. I thought using the not:(.ready) selector in my jquery would fix this, but it's not. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) rather than event binding. The code would look like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("submit", "#donation:not(.ready)", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var amount = $("#firstNumber").val() / 5;
    $("#firstNumber").val(amount);
    $("#submit").val("Donate Now!");
    $("#donation").addClass("ready");
  });
});
```

**ALSO NOTE** - `e.preventDefault()` is a function and thus needs parentheses

Comment: This seems like the best answer. I am new to jquery so didn't think about delegation vs binding. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JamesHamann No worries, it's an easy thing to get tripped up on, even if you have been working with jQuery for a long time. Check out the link that I added in my post for event delegation, I think it does a good job explaining the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are first selecting, then binding your function to the elements found. The list of objects found by the selector doesn't change later on. If you only wish to execute an event handler only once per element and event, try [jQuery.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: This is acceptable, however, the only issue with .one() is that it no longer relies on the "ready" class. Which is an issue if for whatever reason, something errors during the event handler and the class does not get applied. The user would have no way of trying again without refreshing the page. That is extremely unlikely with this very basic example, but if the code gets more complex, and especially if there is an ajax call to go perform a calculation, the chance of error increases significantly, and you need a way for the app to gracefully fail.

Comment: Then check if the element is '.ready' inside the handler. Your answer is better, anyway, @mhodges.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately though, if you throw an if(hasClass(".ready")) in there, if it does not pass, your event handler still gets .off()'d leaving you with the same issue. It's definitely an edge case, but I just think it is worth mentioning. Your solution is valid as long as you code around the intricacies of error handling, I just wanted to point out the caveat of using this solution for the OP and future viewers

Comment: This worked perfect for me. Thank you so much. Didn't even know about one()